# Multi-column Q3ListView and horizontal scrolling

Tags: listview, scrollbar

looking for an answer to the question of getting horizontal scrolling to happen in a Q3ListView with multiple columns.  I assume Q3ListView was used as a quick way to upgrade to 4.x.  Legacy code, and I am tasked with making this thing horizontally scrollable.

The list view has two columns, the first of which contains titles for the content to the right, and so it always shows full text, as none of the text is very long.  The second column can have text that is wider than my 24" screen can show (seen when I roll over it and view the tool tip).

The Q3ListView object was created in Designer with both vScrollBarMode and hScrollBarMode set as Auto (the default).  Since the number of entries is quite large, the vertical scrollbar always shows and I can scroll up and down.  When I see data in the second column that is too long for the width available, it always has an ellipsis (...) at the end with no horizontal scrollbar shown.  If I change the definition of the horizontal scrollback in Designer to AlwaysOn, I see the horizontal scroll bar, but it's greyed, and has no handle, even though there is text too long for the viewable area.

I'm just wondering how I can get a functioning horizontal scroll bar for my Q3ListView that will be able to scroll to show the full text of the second column.  Any suggestions?

--

P.S. - Just tried something new.  I called the setColumnWidthMode() function on the second column of the Q3ListView object as follows:

```
myUi.myValueList->setColumnWidthMode(1, Q3ListView::Maximum);
```

Didn't make any difference.  There is still an ellipsis applied at the end of long text.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Qt3 :)

I don't even have a build I can try it out with as all my versions are compiled without Qt3 clogging up the binaries.

However, I'm expecting that:

```
setColumnWidthMode(1, Q3ListView::Maximum);
```

would do what you want.

If not, then the timing of when you do this might be a factor in your scenario.

For example, it might depend on whether you already added the second column, or on the content being cleared and reset in the meantime. This is because I think the width mode is stored on the column istelf, and so removing and adding a column would mean the mode setting is cleared.

Another way is when you call

> addColumn(label, width);

use a width of -1 to set the width mode to Maximum.

You can try using

```
setColumnWidth(W);
```

to something guaranteed to be big enough just to see if that has the effect you are expecting.

If not, then definitely check your order of events as your column is likely being reconfigured somewhere else, overriding your change.